# How to add label text to DetailDisclosureButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessoryview

I'm working in a iOS Swift 2.0 application. I can't figure out for the life of me on how to set the text on the right side of a `UITableViewCell` just before the disclosure indicator chevron (besides creating a custom `cell.accessoryView`).

Here is a screenshot of the "Settings app" doing exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: cell accessory view screenshot]

Comment: you can achieve it using custom cell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Interface Builder, when setting up your cell, select the Right Detail style:

[image: Right Detail]

Then assign the value to the `detailTextLabel` property:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = "Kilroy Was Here"
```

Answer (score 11):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellId") ?? UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "CellId")
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Main text"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Detail Text"

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to do it programmatically without using the storyboard at all, the easiest way would be:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let viewModel = viewModels[indexPath.row]
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        var config = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()

        config.text = viewModel.title
        config.secondaryText = viewModel.secondaryText
        cell.contentConfiguration = config
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        return cell
    }
```