# How can I set disclosure button to a UItableViewCell

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I want to set a `UITableViewCell` disclosure button but it doesn't work. I am using:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
```

In this function:

```
func tableView ( tableView : UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NsIndwxPath )-->UITableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

or

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var CellIdentifier: String = "Cell"
var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier)
if cell == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(frame: CGRectZero, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
}
cell.accessoryType = .DetailDisclosureButton
return cell
}
```

or you can do it using storyboard
select your tableview cell from Document outline and go to attribute inspector and select disclourse indicator for your cell as shown in the picture

[image]

Comment: you are using                                                                                                   `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cell.accessoryType = .DetailDisclosureButton


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button on the side, use:

```
cell.accessoryType = .DetailButton
```

When it is tapped, do something in this method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Comment: how can I set a string to the `.DetailButton` that is shown in each cell? I mean, I can construct a cell using the indexPath of `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` method and then once I have the cell, how can I set a String value to the cell's DetailButton ? `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`
        `cell?.accessoryView.text // no text property available on accessoryView`

Comment: I believe you have to create a custom accessoryView to do so. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400214/how-to-add-label-text-to-detaildisclosurebutton

Comment: I thought that there was an accessory view provided by default which would adjust itself on the screen same as a UILabel. Thanks